# asp.net validating all controls on a active pageview in multiview through function

Tags: c#, asp.net

Documenting here how to validate all controls on a active page-view in multi-view, will answer my own question.

[edit] = I am doing this function wise as I am looking for a general purpose solution as I am generating certain things on the fly using specific rules and code dumping, instead of manually entering validation on each form control, I can set up a scheme for managing all types of validation I may use.

Problem: In ASP.net I have a multi-view form page that needs all controls being completed before moving on wards to the next active view.

Solution: Iterate through all items on the page and check them whether they have got items within it.

*will add my own code solution in answer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my class solution that can have its function called as on the next page button.

```
namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    public class Validation
    {
        public Validation()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        public bool check_control(Control _control)
        {
            _control.GetType();

            if (_control is TextBox)
            {
                // example of validation
                if((_control as TextBox).Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (_control is DropDownList)
            {

            }
            if (_control is RadioButton)
            {

            }
            if (_control is RadioButtonList)
            {

            }
            return false;
        }

    public bool fn_validator(int current_view = 0, int border = 0, Color? color = null, Panel _panel = null)
    {
        //looops through / iterates all items in form and checks for validation
        color.GetValueOrDefault(Color.Red);
        bool atleastone = false;


         foreach (Control a in _panel.Controls.Cast<Control>())
          {
            if (check_control(a, Color.Red, 4))
            {
                atleastone = true;
            }
          }
         if (atleastone)
         {
            return true;
         }
        return false;
    }






}
```

Modified so adding a panel section in asp.net of what you want to make sure is validated.

Comment: What is wrong with using the aspnet build-in validation?

Comment: Ahh good point I should have addressed, some pages I'm generating certain controls on the fly. The idea is that anyone on the webpages can be very general purpose, and its hard to anticipate what kind of validation I may need.